# How do I dodge/block attacks with a Force Master?

Tags: blade-and-soul

I've recently started playing the game, and one thing that ticks me, comparing to [tera](/questions/tagged/tera) is that, for the love of my life, I can't avoid **any damage at all**!

This leads me to die in less than 1 minute with 2 enemies.

I am aware of <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, but it is very clucky, slow, delayed and it has 10 seconds of cooldown, leading to the same situation as before.

But, sometimes, out of nowhere, I see that the damage was blocked.
I really don't understand how that happens. I just slowly move to it's back or something.

In short, the question is: How do I dodge/block attacks with a Force Master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the backstep since it has a 36 second cooldown, and you can eventually level it up to the frost step in which you can freeze the area you step out of. Use q and e to escape damage, and at level 13 there's really not much to say since most of your skills for heal and cc aren't out yet, plus you don't have that many points in the skill tree.

I hit 45 about a week ago, and the best thing to do against blade dancers is to kite them. Use the right click frost for slow, and 2 for daze, 3 for freeze and follow up with 1 to knock back stun. I'm not sure if the fire stance x skills came out for you yet or not, but as you level up you can eventually insta cast it. I use mostly that and the frost stance z and x for slow, cc, and burst. Control the TAB key frost and your frost stance c and v for survival. C is a really powerful skill if you add the points right.

Honestly fm have pretty powerful burst and cc, you just have to have pvp experience. Took me 60 rounds of ranked to get enough experience to get to gold

Comment: That is some really good insight! Thank you! That is the kind of answer I was looking for. Just a tip: You can format your keys to look like keys by using `<kbd>KEY</kbd>` (doesn't work on comments). It will stick them out of the text and helps on readability. Your tip against blade dancers is really good, in my humble opinion. I must try out your attack sequence. I have tons of troubles with E and Q on my blade dancer (level 27, at the time of writting this). But hopefully, I will get there. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, you can also use <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>. These require you to have a target, but you will quickly move behind your target a few meters away. It moves you a surprisingly long distance. I don't know if it has iframes, but I know it's an option.

Edit:

Note also you can use ice shield (<kbd>TAB</kbd>), even though it isn't a dodge. There is also random chance to block damage, that's probably what you saw. But you will have no control over that.

Comment: Surelly it is available on Blade Dancers, but I'm not aware of it being available on Force Masters. I will try it tomorrow and will confirm it to you.

Comment: I'm quite sad to report that that Q and E don't work. The ice shield is unavailable at level 13. The random block is useless since I have no control over it. With the added bugged out hit detection, it is nearly impossible to survive.

Comment: What do you mean that they don't work? Why are you limited to what spells you have at level 13?

Comment: `What do you mean that they don't work?` --> I mean that they don't have any effect at all, oposingly to Blade Dancers which move to the front or back of the enemy. `Why are you limited to what spells you have at level13?` --> Well, I am level 13. If I don't have a level 16 skill unlocked, I can't use it.

Comment: Your question should clarify your requirements. Also you should be asking with level 45 in mind. You won't be 13 forever.

Comment: You can't asume that everybody is playing on end-game level (level 45, I assume) in a game that was released to general public less than 2 weeks ago.